# How to tell what is the assigned internal DNS based on the internal LoadBalancer description?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an internal load balancer:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "kind": "Service",
        "metadata": {
          "annotations": {
            "networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type": "Internal"
          },
          "labels": {
            "app.kubernetes.io/environment": "review",
            "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "review-contra-database-9afc94a1",
            "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "helm",
            "app.kubernetes.io/name": "review-contra-database-9afc94a1",
            "app.kubernetes.io/version": "25f495d5",
            "contra.com/app-name": "review-contra-database-9afc94a1"
          },
          "name": "review-contra-database-9afc94a1-internal",
          "namespace": "review-9afc94a1"
        },
        "spec": {
          "externalTrafficPolicy": "Cluster",
          "ports": [
            {
              "name": "postgres",
              "port": 5432,
              "protocol": "TCP",
              "targetPort": 6432
            }
          ],
          "selector": {
            "app.kubernetes.io/environment": "review",
            "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "review-contra-database-9afc94a1",
            "app.kubernetes.io/name": "review-contra-database-9afc94a1"
          },
          "type": "LoadBalancer"
        }
      }
    networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: Internal
  creationTimestamp: "2023-04-14T18:36:00Z"
  finalizers:
  - gke.networking.io/l4-ilb-v1
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/environment: review
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: review-contra-database-9afc94a1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: review-contra-database-9afc94a1
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 25f495d5
    contra.com/app-name: review-contra-database-9afc94a1
  name: review-contra-database-9afc94a1-internal
  namespace: review-9afc94a1
  resourceVersion: "385423413"
  uid: 28b5bdd4-ef2e-4f8e-b515-7804354bf851
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 10.16.12.215
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.16.12.215
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: postgres
    nodePort: 30853
    port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6432
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/environment: review
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: review-contra-database-9afc94a1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: review-contra-database-9afc94a1
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.128.0.9
```

From what I understand, [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/dns-names) says that this load balancer is automatically assigned an internal DNS record.

```
SERVICE_LABEL.FORWARDING_RULE_NAME.il4.REGION.lb.PROJECT_ID.internal
```

However, while I know `PROJECT_ID` and `REGION`, I am not clear what the `SERVICE_LABEL` and `FORWARDING_RULE_NAME` maps to.

How do derive this information or better set a hand picked hostname?

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the internal DNS name once the internal load balancer is created. Once you check the created internal load balancer there is an information shows “DNS name”

Based on my replication, the only way to create service_label is through UI (console) under “Frontend Configuration”.

I tried to configure this under GKE>Service&Ingress but there is no way to create service_label. For this concern I think we can create a feature request[1].

Another observation upon replicating this concern is that service_label cannot be edited. This can only be created when creating the Internal Load Balancer.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests